# rpm-maven-plugin how to control the name under which rpm is stored in m2 repository?

Tags: maven-3, rpm-maven-plugin, maven-install-plugin

Our organization has a convention for naming rpms.  Typically, the rpm will have a shorter base name than the Maven project.  There is also a convention around how releases are named.  So we want a name like
`${shortname}-${project.version}-${release}.noarch.rpm`.

I want to build such rpms using the rpm-maven-plugin rather than older nmake technology.

And this is easily accomplished using the plugin's parameters.  The rpm generated in the target directory has the desired name.

However, when `mvn install` installs this rpm into the maven repository, it insists on storing it the "maven way": `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.rpm`

I want the rpm stored in the standard maven repository directory using the name that is initially created on package.

How may I accomplish this?

Update:
I tried using the maven-install-plugin (install-file goal) and did not get the results I was after.  But this was partly because I wasn't invoking it properly.  It wasn't being invoked.  If you define an install-file goal, it must be explicitly tied to the install phase.  Doing so, ie, adding a `<phase>install</phase>` to the configuration at least invoked the execution of the install that I wanted but it still did not allow me to name the rpm as desired.

Answer (score 3):

According to Karl Heinz Marbaise, a committer on the Apache Maven Project, [what I am trying to do is impossible, and should not be attempted.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201512.mbox/ajax/%3C5665E3EE.2070105%40gmx.de%3E)

However, I need what I need, and have found a compromise that gives me most of that.  The only thing I had to sacrifice was the assumption that the repository RPM must live in the same repository directory as the rest of the project.  This is a very minor sacrifice.  Once I make that, I can store the rpm, named as I want it to be, in a directory of the Maven repository, named with the short name.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>install-rpm</id>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/rpm/${rpm.name}/RPMS/noarch/${rpm.name}-${project.version}-${rpm.release}.noarch.rpm</file>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}.rpms</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${rpm.name}</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}-${rpm.release}</version>
                                <classifier>noarch</classifier>
                                <packaging>rpm</packaging>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using a groupId of `${project.groupId}.rpms` rather than just `${project.groupId}` allows all rpms built this way to live outside of the main branch of the repository, which is useful in our situation.

Using a version of `${project.version}-${rpm.release}` rather than just `${project.version}` allows the release to be incorporated into the name.

And the `noarch` classifier gets that into the name as well.